# Pyspark - Renaming files according to their modification date

Tags: python, pyspark, databricks

I've created a Python script to rename files according to their modification date. I add 1 day to the date on the file if the file was modified between a defined time slot. I also need to check that when the file is renamed with the correct date it doesn't overwrite an existing file, otherwise it adds a timestamp to the file name.

I'm having a few problems, particularly with the renaming process, which adds the timestamps each time.

Can you help me correct my errors?

I'd also like to add that I'm running the script on a `databricks` cluster and renaming the files on a storage blob on azure.

```
import os
import time
import re
import logging
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import shutil

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

def run_fast_scandir(dir, ext):
    subfolders, files = [], []

    for f in os.scandir(dir):
        if f.is_dir():
            subfolders.append(f.path)
        if f.is_file():
            if os.path.splitext(f.name)[1].lower() in ext:
                files.append(f.path)

    for dir in list(subfolders):
        sf, f = run_fast_scandir(dir, ext)
        subfolders.extend(sf)
        files.extend(f)
    return subfolders, files

def move_and_rename_file(src_path, dest_path):
    try:
        shutil.move(src_path, dest_path)
        logger.info(f"Moved and renamed: {os.path.basename(src_path)} to {os.path.basename(dest_path)}")
        return True
    except Exception as e:
        logger.error(f"Error moving/renaming {src_path} to {dest_path}: {str(e)}")
        return False

def generate_new_filename(file_item, timestamp):
    base_name, extension = os.path.splitext(file_item)
    return f"{base_name}_{timestamp}{extension}"

def saveExistingFiles(existing_files, dest_path):
    timestamp = time.strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S", time.localtime())
    
    for file_path in existing_files:
        new_file_name = generate_new_filename(os.path.basename(file_path), timestamp)
        dest_path_with_timestamp = os.path.join(dest_path, new_file_name)

        try:
            shutil.move(file_path, dest_path_with_timestamp)
            logger.info(f"Renamed existing file: {os.path.basename(file_path)} to {os.path.basename(dest_path_with_timestamp)}")
        except Exception as e:
            logger.error(f"Error renaming existing file {file_path}: {str(e)}")

def process_files(adls_path):
    all_files = run_fast_scandir(adls_path, ['.'])
    file_details = []

    for file_path in all_files[1]:
        try:
            file_info = dbutils.fs.ls(file_path)
            if file_info:
                file_details.append((file_path, file_info[0].modificationTime))
        except Exception as e:
            logger.error(f"Error getting details for {file_path}: {str(e)}")

    # Sort files based on modification time
    file_details.sort(key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)

    num_processed_files = 0

    for file_path, modification_time in file_details:
        try:
            ti_m = modification_time / 1000
            if re.search(r'\d{8}', os.path.basename(file_path)):
                modified_hour = time.localtime(ti_m).tm_hour
                if 14 <= modified_hour <= 23:
                    file_item = os.path.basename(file_path)
                    current_date = file_item.split('-')[1].split('.')[0]
                    new_date = (datetime.fromtimestamp(ti_m) + timedelta(days=1)).strftime("%Y%m%d")
                    new_file_name = file_item.replace(current_date, new_date)
                    dest_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(file_path), new_file_name)

                    existing_files = [entry[0] for entry in file_details if entry[0] != file_path]

                    if dest_path in existing_files:
                        saveExistingFiles([dest_path], os.path.dirname(file_path))
                    else:
                        if move_and_rename_file(file_path, dest_path):
                            num_processed_files += 1

        except Exception as e:
            logger.error(f"Error processing {file_path}: {str(e)}")

    return num_processed_files, [entry[0] for entry in file_details]


if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
        adls_path = 'path/to/my/folder'

        logger.info(f"Current Working directory: {os.getcwd()}")
        logger.info(f"Processing Folder: {adls_path}")

        num_processed_files, all_files = process_files(adls_path)

        logger.info(f"\nNumber of files after processing: {num_processed_files}")
        logger.info(f"Files after processing: {all_files}")
        logger.info("Operation completed.")

    except Exception as e:
        logger.exception(f"An unexpected error occurred: {str(e)}")
```